# D3 ,update to a two level element

Tags: arrays, d3.js, nested

i've stuck in this problem for several days,
hope someone can help me out here,thanks

the things i'm trying to do is  this

i have a bunch of links grouped according to the nodes that it related

the svg is like this

```
<g class = "edge" >
<path d="M 10,20L 176.04599778748948,300.5015249766384" ></path>
<path  d="M 30,40L 176.04599778748948,300.5015249766384" ></path>
</g>
<g class = "edge" >
<path d="M 50,60L 176.04599778748948,300.5015249766384" ></path>
<path d="M 70,80L 176.04599778748948,300.5015249766384" ></path>
</g>
```

and data set is like

```
  var nodes = [
    [" start", null, 0, [
        ["home", 1711, 1]
    ]],
    ["home", null, 4.279281698E9, [
        [" stop", 1173, 1]
    ]],
    [" stop", null, 0, []]
];

   var layout = [
    [100, 200,10],
    [300, 300,50],
    [50, 50,10]
];
```

i try to init the edges:

```
var svg_edges = svg.append("g").attr("class", STYLE.edges)
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodes,function(d){ return d[0];}).enter().append("g").selectAll("path")
      .data(function(d) { return d[3]; },function(d){return d[0]})
      svg_edges.enter().append("path")
    drawEdge(svg_edges,false);
        /* Exit. */
    svg_edges.exit().remove();
```

then i want to do a update for these group of edges like

```
 function update (){
edges = svg.select("g." + STYLE.edges).selectAll("g").data(nodes,function(d){ return d[0];}) 
       edges = edges.selectAll("path").data(function(d){ return d[3]},function(d){return d[0]})
       edges.enter().append("path")
       drawEdge(edges,true)

       edges.exit().remove();
}
```

and the update didn't work,it only adds or delete a half of links, does someone do this before, try to update a nested selection,thanks ~~

===============================
finally, i find the solution 
here is what i do

```
 /* Update the edges. */
       group = svg.select("g." + STYLE.edges).selectAll("g").data(nodes,function(d){ return d[0];});
       edges1=group.enter().append("g").selectAll("path").data(function(d){return d[3]})
       edges2=group.selectAll("path").data(function(d){return d[3]})
       edges1.enter().append("path")
       edges2.enter().append("path")
       drawEdge(edges1,true)
       drawEdge(edges2,true)
       edges1.exit().remove();
       edges2.exit().remove();
       group.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the index of the higher-level data as an additional argument to the functions to set attributes etc. That is, instead of `function(d, i)` where `d` is the current data element and `i` the current index, you can use `function(d, i, j)` where `j` is the index of the current data element at the higher level.

You can then use this index to retrieve the relevant higher-level data. The code would look something like this:

```
svg_edges.enter().append("path")
         .attr("id", function(d, i, j) { return "g-" + j + "-path-" + i; });
```

Full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wkkUt/).

Comment: HI Lars,thanks for ur response,i've followed the example that you gave me, unfortunately, it didn't work,i did sth like this                data(function(d) { return d[3]; },function(d, i, j) {return "g-" + j + "-path-" + i; })  , varable j is undefined

Comment: You can't do that in the data matching function -- what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: hello lars, i just reorgnised my question, hope that would be more clear,thanks

Comment: You should be able to do it like that. Did you check whether the new data are matched as you would expect them to?

Comment: yep, new data is totally correct, for example when i do a update, it should add 4 edges,but it added only two, there is a half of edges missing, so i thought maybe i didn't get the right seletor ?

Comment: Are the edges that are missing getting matched to existing elements, i.e. are they in the update selection?